# How to get names of all S3 buckets in AWS with Python3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3

I've done a little experimentation with Python3 and am using it with AWS.

The following code will list all S3 buckets in my account in a given region:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import boto3

session = boto3.Session(profile_name='my_profile',region_name='us-west-2')

s3 = session.resource('s3')

for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
        print(bucket.name)
```

Just for the sake of understanding, when I tried to do it another way:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import boto3

session = boto3.Session(profile_name='my_profile',region_name='us-west-2')

s3 = session.resource('s3')

s3_bucket_list = s3.buckets.all()

print(*s3_bucket_list.s3.Bucket.name)
```

... I get this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./scratch9.py", line 11, in 
    print(*s3_bucket_list.s3.Bucket.name)
AttributeError: 's3.bucketsCollection' object has no attribute 's3'

Does anyone have an idea of what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: It worked OK for me. Boto3 v1.9.16, Python 3.7.0 on Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing, and solved it now: Just use `s3_bucket_list.name`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).